# Loop to paint different images?

Tags: java

I would like to have a loop that will run through each of the images i have. I would  like to draw them to the screen and it works fine if i draw each image separately but it uses a lot of code. Whilst using a loop to paint each image should uuse a lot less code. This is my code.

```
String image[] = {"carA", "carB"};
        for(int i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
        g.drawImage(image[i].getImage(), image[i].getX(), image[i].getY(),
                image[i].getWidth(), image[i].getHeight(), this);
        }
```

It says the problem is that strings are being used. The getX() and getY() etc finds out the x and y coordinates.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Perhaps you intent your array to be of a different type than String[], probably a class wrapping the image and holding its position and size.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call getImage /getX / getY on the String object.
You should load your Image first into the Image object like that

```
Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(image[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) method, it can draw strings:

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize all data about images, try this example:

```
String imageDatas[][] = {
        {"image_path_1.jpg", "0", "0", "100", "100"},
        {"image_path_2.jpg", "100", "0", "100", "100"}
};
for (String[] imageData : imageDatas) {
    String filePath = imageData[0];
    int x = Integer.parseInt(imageData[1]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(imageData[2]);
    int width = Integer.parseInt(imageData[3]);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(imageData[4]);

    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filePath);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String is a type that store characters. So it can not be used for your requirements.

To meet the requirements you should crate own type.

Good place to start i to create a interface that your class will be using.

```
public interface IMichaelImage {

   int getX();
   int getY();
   Image getImage();

}
```

Then you need to create a class that will be able to store the information that you program logic will use

```
public MichaelImage implements IMichaelImage { 

  private int x = 0;
  private int y = 0; 
  private Image image;

  public MichaelImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override
  public int getX() {
     return this.x;
  ]

  @Override 
  public int getY() {
    return this.x;
  }

  public Image getImage() {
    return this.image;

  }

}
```

On the and you will have something like this

```
 Collection<IMichaelImage> images = loadImages();

  for(IMichaelImage image : images) {
    g.drawImage(image.getImage(), image.getX(), image.getY());
  }
```